# Finding the largest blob in a black/white image

Tags: r, opencv

I have this picture: [image: im]
I want to create a mask from this image, to place on top of the original image. The mask I want to obtain is the black part at the top.

I tried to use simpleBlobDetector from OpenCV to try to detect the white part as one big blob. I do not obtain the results I am hoping for and am unsure what to do.

R has been used, but my question is not specifically on how to achieve this in R. The result I have is below the code.

```
library(Rvision)
x <- simpleBlobDetector(im, min_threshold = 0, max_threshold = 255)
plot(x)
```

[image: blobs]

I do not understand why those three black boxes are selected as blobs, while there are a lot more of those black boxes that are not selected.

**EDIT:** when I add `blob_color = 255` so white blobs are searched, nothing is detected.

Comment: I don't know R, but a couple of ideas are... 1) try inverting your image before running the blob detector, 2) try thresholding your image prior to running the blob detector, 3) try adding a white border a few pixels wide all around the image before running the blob detector.

Comment: Tried out 1 & 3 but had the same result. What thresholds would you suggest to use? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I meant a simple 50% threshold of your image before the blob detector. All pixels under 128 become pure black, all other pixels become pure white.

Comment: Ah my bad. They already are.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work out, I don't know anything about R to suggest anything else. Hopefully someone else will help you out. Good luck!

Comment: If all of the images that you want to process have the region to be masked at the top, you can set the top left corner as the seed point and use [`floodFill`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#floodfill). I don't know about R, but in C++ and Python there's an option to return a mask of the filled region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this using OpenCV:

```
// read input image
Mat inputImg = imread("test1.tif", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

// create binary image
Mat binImg;
threshold(inputImg, binImg, 254, 1, THRESH_BINARY_INV);

// compute connected components
Mat labelImg;
connectedComponents(binImg, labelImg, 8, CV_16U);

// compute histogram
Mat histogram;
int histSize = 256;
float range[] = { 0, 256 } ;
const float* histRange = { range };
calcHist(&labelImg, 1, 0, Mat(), histogram, 1, &histSize, &histRange, true, false);

// retrieve maximal population
float maxVal = 0;
int maxIdx;
for (int i=1; i<histSize; ++i) {
    if (histogram.at<float>(i) > maxVal) {
        maxVal = histogram.at<float>(i);
        maxIdx = i;
    }
}

// create output mask with bigest population
Mat resImg;
threshold(labelImg, labelImg, maxIdx, 0, THRESH_TOZERO_INV);
threshold(labelImg, resImg, maxIdx-1, 1, THRESH_BINARY);

// write result
imwrite("res.tif", resImg);
```

And you should obtain something like this:

[image: resulting mask image]

Answer (score -1):

I think you can convert input to bianry, then extract connected components, compute associated histogram and simply keep (by thresholding) histogram class with highest population
Regards